# why are the dates not being generated properly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, date

I am using a function in Angular JS to generate the dates for the past one week starting from today's date. I am storing these dates in an array and then using that array to flood a dropdown.
The following is the code that is being used by me.

```
generate() {
    this.date_new = [];
    var date = new Date();
    var date1 = new Date();
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        date.setDate(date1.getDate() - i);
        var a = date.toString();
        var str = this.convert(a);
        this.date_new.push(str);
    }
}
```

Here convert is a function which is being used to convert the dates to the required format. A screenshot of generated dates is attached below.

[image: The generated dates]

As evident from the screenshot, the last two dates are incorrect. Can somebody explain to me, what the problem is?

Comment: Could you also share the function `this.convert()` ?

Comment: convert(date)
  {
    var str=date.split(" ");

    return str[0]+" "+str[1]+" "+str[2]+" "+str[3]

  }

Comment: I have tested this function.It is not working for today's date.

Comment: By testing i mean pure javascript code , without any view associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

> The setDate() method sets the day of the Date object relative to the
>   beginning of the currently set month.

The above is from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate).

Your code works for the first 5 dates, but once you are modifying your February date with `-1`, it sets the day relative to the current month e.g. February. So this will turn into January (as you are setting the day to -1), same happens in the next iteration and you get December.

For an easy fix you can just set the `date` variable to `new Date()` in the first line of your `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is using the same `date` variable in the loop. You need to re-initialize it.

As can be seen in **Parameters Value** section in the [link here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setdate.asp). Zero and negative values in `setDate()` sets the date from previous month.

Hence at `setDate(0)`, date value is set to last day of Feb. Now since you are using the same variable, `setDate(-1)` takes the previous month from Feb hence you get Jan.

You need to change the code to something like this:

```
generate() {
    this.date_new = [];
    var date1 = new Date();
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        // re-initialize date
        var date = new Date();
        date.setDate(date1.getDate() - i);
        var a = date.toString();
        var str = this.convert(a);
        this.date_new.push(str);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks @Royson ,However an explaination for this might help.

Comment: @AshutoshKumar I have added a brief explanation. If you think it addresses your query well then mark the answer as accepted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that negative numbers inside the setDate method don't work quite well.

Please update the code to something like below:

```
this.date_new = [];
var date = new Date();
var date1 = new Date();
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    date= new Date(date1.getFullYear(), date1.getMonth(),date1.getDate()-i);
    var a = date.toString();
    var str = this.convert(a);
    this.date_new.push(str);
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.